# Input Filter - Regex for Two Decimals

Tags: java, android, regex, android-edittext

I am trying to create a regex for my `EditText` to only allow input that is in dollar format. However it is not working.

```
public class DecimalInputFilter implements InputFilter {

    Pattern mPattern;

    public DecimalInputFilter() {
        mPattern=Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+([.][0-9]{2})?$");
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        Matcher matcher=mPattern.matcher(dest);
        if(!matcher.matches())
            return "";
        return null;
    }

}
```

The Regex thought process -

- At least one numeric character
- a dot followed by exactly two numeric characters (Optional)

When I try to apply this, it does not allow me to input any numbers. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you type in the editText, you receive the CharSequence in source, and your already entered string in dest, so instead try

```
Matcher matcher=mPattern.matcher(dest.toString() + source.toString());
```

and use the regex as `^[0-9]+([.][0-9]{0,2})?$`

The above regex is also going to except 4. but nothing can be done as we can enter only one char at a time, so to take care of that you can put a final regex check after submitting the value.

Comment: @RickSanchez no, it still fails the matches check.

Comment: @RickSanchez no, nothing at all.

Comment: @Alan have you changed from dest to source?

Comment: @RickSanchez sorry I was wrong, changing it to source only allows me to enter numbers, no decimals. How do I get decimals in?

Comment: @Alan I think this regex will work for you ^[0-9]+([.][0-9]{0,2})?$

Comment: @RickSanchez just to note, this will allow an entry like "6.", which may or may not be considered ok.

Comment: @sweaver2112 It has to be done this way as we can enter only one character at a time, to compensate that one more check can be put after submitting the value.

Comment: you should put that regex in your answer I think. +1 either way

Comment: @RickSanchez hmm... i thought your regex would work, but it still only lets me enter numbers. The decimal point is blocked.

Comment: @RickSanchez works great. thank you. Switched checked answer to you due to simpler answer

Answer (score 5):

Use the next filter function:

```
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    if (source.equals("")) return null; // Para el backspace
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(dest);
    builder.replace(dstart, dend, source.subSequence(start, end).toString());
    Matcher matcher=mPattern.matcher(builder);
    if(!matcher.matches())
        return "";
    return null;
}
```

Because if you match on builder it will let you know if the final string matches the proposed expression, otherwise it returns the empty string.

Answer (score 3):

You can try out the following filter, use `MAX_NUMBER` to set the maximum number of digits before the dot and `PRECISION`to set the precision number after the dot.

```
public class DecimalInputFilter implements InputFilter {
    private static final int MAX_NUMBER = 10;
    private static final int PRECISION = 2;

    public DecimalInputFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(dest);
        builder.replace(dstart, dend, source.subSequence(start, end).toString());

        if (!builder.toString().matches("(([0-9]{1})([0-9]{0,"+(MAX_NUMBER-1)+"})?)?(\\.[0-9]{0,"+PRECISION+"})?")) {
            if(source.length() == 0)
                return dest.subSequence(dstart, dend);
            return "";
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: this works, could you explain the Regex and the `builder.replace`?

Comment: For the regex, the first part is asking for at least one number, the second part allows the input of 0 to MAX_NUMBER additional numbers and the final part allows the input of 2 digits after the comma but no digits at all is also allowed (i.e. 20 / 20.1 / 20.12 are allowed). Concerning the replace I don't clearly remember, I might have taken this part that from another SO question, there is maybe a way to make it more simple...

Comment: @Alan You know, it's really weird, in your question you asked what you might be missing and I gave you right explanation what exactly you're missing, however you just choose the answer that "works" not even bothering what exactly you were missing and why your code didn't work for you.

Comment: @YoannHercouet what about "20." input? If it's not allowed, he won't be able to enter the decimal part at all.

Comment: @AlexBerdnikov This is also allowed, I then convert the text entered into a `float` to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
Matcher matcher=mPattern.matcher(dest);
if(!matcher.matches())
    return "";
```

It means that all your input is replaced with `""` if your edit text is not matched with your regex, which, I assume, is the case initially since it's probably an empty string.

Comment: wouldn't the filter only run upon recieving some input?

Comment: @sweaver2112, yes, but he is matching it against the destination spannable which is not modified yet.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you're experiencing this because your filter processes the input on every entered symbol and until you enter all the symbols your regexp simply don't match to the input. When you try to enter the very first symbols, let's say it's "2", it doesn't match to the entire regexp. So you either have to alter your regexp and make point and decimal parts of it optional, or you have to apply the filter in some more explicit way when the input is done (like on "send/apply" button click action).

As a side note, consider using `android:inputType` attribute for your `EditText` element, in 9 of 10 cases it covers all your needs in filtering the input; in you case I suggest you use "numberDecimal" type.

**EDIT**: be aware that even though your regexp marks the decimal part of the input as optional, `Matcher.matches()` method returns `true` only if it matches the entire regexp.

From Matcher class JavaDoc:

> Tries to match the Pattern against the entire region (or the
>        entire input, if no region has been set).
>        Returns true if (and only if) the Pattern matches the entire
>        region.

Comment: but aren't I already making it optional with the `?` at the end of the decimal expression

Comment: @Alan: yup, the regex itself seems fine. It will match a "2"

Comment: If you and other guys downvoting me read documentation carefully, you would see that it clearly states that matches() method "returns true if (and only if) the Pattern matches the entire region."

Comment: yes, and a number completely satisfies this simple regex...unless i'm missing something?

Comment: @sweaver2112 I pointed out what he is missing above in both comments thread and my answer post.

Comment: @AlexBerdnikov don't be sour about it. I personally didn't downvote you. I figured out what the issue was with my regex, but I don't know how to change it to work and Yoann's regex does what I was asking for in the question.

Comment: @Alan Not only your regexp was wrong. Your misuse of Matcher.matches() method was what didn't allow you even to enter the first digit. That is what you asked in the beginning. But who cares when there's simply different working solution :)

Comment: @AlexBerdnikov why do you think I posted the entire class instead of JUST the regex... :) ? Instead of being so literal, you can see what goal I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Alan of course I see what goal you were trying to achieve, and I just explained what exactly doesn't work in your solution. BTW, the answer of Rick Sanchez that you accepted states absolutely the same as mine and at the same time my answer was given earlier. I simply don't understand people like you here on SO. Where's the  logic?